# Construction of infinite cyclic cover of knot exterior using seifert surface

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory

To construct infinite cyclic cover of knot exterior using seifert surface following the Lickorish's textbook, I think that we must choose a tubular neighborhood $T$ and a Seifert surface $F$ of the given knot $K$ such that $\partial T$ and $F$ intersect transversally and $T\cap F$ is a collar of $F$. Then how can we prove the existence of such $T$ and $F$?

(I only realized that transversality theorem assures the existence of $T$ and $F$ satisfying the first condition.)

[image]

Comment: I don't have Lickorish right with me, so I am not sure exactly what you are looking for here.  You know that $T$ and $F$ exist for other reasons.  So all you really need to do is prove they are transversal.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Even if we get $T$ and $F$ such that $\partial T$ and $F$ are transversal,  $T\cap F$ is not necessarily a collar of $F$, I think. How can we get $T$ and $F$ satisfying the whole conditions?

Comment: Well $\partial T$ and $F$ are both surfaces and we can assume the intersection is transversal.  So $\partial T \cap F$ is a collection of 1-manifolds.  It should be straight forward to convince yourself this is actually a collection of circles, not arcs.  Then you need to use a standard inner most disk argument to see that there are only a collection of circles that are parallel to the knot.  Then a similar argument (inner most annulus?) to say these are all unnecessary, except for one.  Then you have it.  The collar looks like you expect it to.

Comment: I understood that $\partial T \cap F$ is a collection of circles. But I am not familiar with this field, so I don't know what exactly you mean by innermost disk argument (and also "innermost annulus argument"). I did some research and guessed that the argument is to focus on the innermost disk and reduce the number of components of $\partial T \cap F$ by cut or isotopy.  But I have no idea what to do in this case.

Comment: Since the intersection is a finite collection of circles which they themselves do not intersect, there is at least one circle which is an innermost circle.  This circle must bound disks in both $F$ and $\partial T$. (If it didn't, then either it is the boundary of an innermost annulus or there is a circle that is more inner.)  There exists an isotopy to remove this the bounded disks and the circle.  Then by induction, you can remove all circles that bound disks.  If you have any circles which do not bound disks, then they are boundaries to annuli and a similar argument will work.

Comment: Might there be a circle that does not bound any disks in $F$ and is not even parallel to $\partial F$? How can such circles be removed?

Comment: (Please see a picture I added.)

Comment: In your picture, $T$ is not yet small enough... We are allowed to choose *any* tubular neighbourhood, so we should take one that is very small "compared to $K$ and to $F$".

Comment: As @SamNead said, it is just a bit too large.  Since the intersection bounds a disk in $T$, you can retract it back and reduce the number of intersections.

Comment: My thanks to both of you. I still can't convince myself about details due to lack of my background and maybe need more time to understand completely, so this is my last question in this time: how can we construct an (smooth) isotopy which eliminates the innermost circle?

Answer (score 0):

Fix a metric on $S^3$ (or on $\mathbb{R}^3$).  One approach is to choose $F$ first, and choose $T$ second, sufficiently small and nice with respect to $K$ and $F$. For example:

Suppose that $K$ is smooth with non-vanishing tangent. We project $K$ onto a generic plane to obtain a diagram.  We build $F$ using Seifert's algorithm - we smooth the crossings of the diagram according to the orientation, cap off all circles with disks, and then attach half-twisted bands to obtain $F$ with $\partial F = K$.

Since there are only finitely many disks, and finitely many half-twisted bands, and since the projection was generic, we have a fairly nice local model for each disk and half-twisted band.  Compactness gives us a small $\epsilon$ so that the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood $T$ of $K$ meets each disk and half-twisted band in a collection of small disks; these piece together to give a collar for $F$.

Comment: Thank you. Why (for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ ) $\epsilon$-neighborhood is a tubular neighborhood of $K$, and its intersection with $F$ is a collar?